# Propel - multiple foreign key to third table in a crossref table

Tags: propel

In my schema, I have a model Person and a model Project many-to-many related by a cross-ref table called ProjectView. Each ProjectView is related to two Transactions, AuthorTransaction and ViewerTransaction.

```
Person ========== ProjectView ============== Model
                   ||      ||
                   ||      ||
                   ||      ||
                  Transaction
```

I have made the following schema:

```
<table name="Project_View" isCrossRef="true">
    <column name="project_id"
        primaryKey="true"
        type="BIGINT"
        phpType="int"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="Project"
        phpName="ViewedProject"
        onDelete="cascade"
        onUpdate="cascade">
        <reference local="project_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <column name="viewer_id" primaryKey="true" type="BIGINT" phpType="int"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="Person"
        phpName="Viewer"
        onDelete="cascade"
        onUpdate="cascade">
        <reference local="viewer_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <column name="viewer_transaction_id" type="BIGINT" phpType="int"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="Transaction"
        phpName="ViewerTransaction"
        onDelete="restrict"
        onUpdate="restrict">
        <reference local="viewer_transaction_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <column name="author_transaction_id" type="BIGINT" phpType="int"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="Transaction"
        phpName="AuthorTransaction"
        onDelete="restrict"
        onUpdate="restrict">
        <reference local="author_transaction_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
</table>
```

However, the generated Transaction class has duplicated names inside, rendering the model unusable. Is this unsupported in Propel 2.0?